# How set a null date (0000-00-00) in to a spring property?

Tags: spring, date, datepicker, null

I'm trying to set  the value 0000-00-00 with an  expression on a spring property like this, is any expression for to do this?

this is my code

I tried without any value but the date is 01-01-1901 and I need 0000-00-00
Any advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you would like to use that property in other context, so 0000-00-00 doesn't exist in Java as a Date. 
Solution (the property value should be 0):

```
new Date(0) //does correspond to January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
```